# separator and label below image in gallery custom UI office

Tags: ms-office, ribbon

I've been reading quite a lot on creating a custom ribbon for Microsoft Office Powerpoint, but I can't figure out how to do these two things in a gallery for Powerpoint 2010:

- Insert labeled separators in a gallery
- Display the label below the image and not to the right

This is how the gallery is in the xml :

```
<gallery id="customslides" label="Custom Slides" columns="3" rows="10" itemWidth="300" 
itemHeight="225" getItemLabel="customslides_getName" getImage="customslides_getImage"
getItemCount="customslides_getItemCount" getItemImage="customslides_getItemImage" 
onAction="customslides_Click" showItemLabel="true" invalidateContentOnDrop="true" size="large">
        <button id="managecustomslides" label="Manage custom library" imageMso="ControlsGallery" onAction="manageslides_Click"/>
</gallery>
```

I'd like it to look like the Page Layout\Themes of Excel 2010 ([Link for the image](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/34/1408459233-themes.png)).
It has both labeled separators ("Built-In" and "From Office.com") and for each Item, the ItemLabel is below the ItemImage.